# AngularJS - how do show element on odd number of clicks anywhere on browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown bar with class "navigation-dropdown" that currently shows when this variable called "dropdown" is true (dropdown value is flipped when the navbar is clicked). So the only way to close the dropdown is to click in the navbar again. Is there a way to close the dropdown by clicking anywhere in the body?

Code sample:

```
 <nav class="navigation-nav hide-mobile" ng-controller="LeftNavCtrl" ng-click="dropdown=!dropdown">
    <h2>Dropdown</h2>
    <ul class="navigation-dropdown" ng-show="dropdown" ng-click="dropdown=!dropdown">
     <li class="navigation-dropdown__item">
       <a>Account</a>
     </li>

    <li class="navigation-dropdown__item">
      <a>Help</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: You could try using an `ng-blur` to set a scope variable to utilize for the check, for `ng-show`. `ng-blur` is when the container loses focus, which sounds like exactly what you need/want: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".navigation-nav").length) {
        $scope.dropdown = false;
    }
    $scope.$apply()
})
```

It sets value of dropdown to `false` if anywhere on `document` is clicked that is not `.navigation-nav` or a child of `.navigation-nav`.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x89dbbw1/7/